# Naming convention for base controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, naming-conventions

In MVC-3 my application some controllers do similar things (CRUD and Index). Therefore I have created an abstract base controller in which the similar tasks are implemented. The other controller simply extend the base controller.

Now, everything is working just fine. But I am confused with the naming of the base controller. All controller class names must end with 'Controller' to make MVC work properly. However, my base controller will never be used directly. Therefore, it NEED NOT end with 'Controller'. Also, as it does not do the actual task of a controller, I think it should not sound like a controller.

So, what should be the name of my base controller? Which one is better:
`MyBaseController` or `MyControllerBase` or `JustLikeOtherAbstractClasses` ?

Comment: I have read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181597/what-are-the-naming-guidelines-for-asp-net-controls. Did not help much.

Comment: We use `MyControllerBase` in our projects. I think there is no general guideline for naming Controller base classes. Use whatever name you like, just stay consistent.

Comment: @nemesv: `MyControllerBase` is what I also think is  better. And I will stay consistent. Why don't you make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our projects we are using the `MyControllerBase` naming convention. Because there is no guideline/convention how a `Controller` base class should be named you can use whatever name you like, just stay consistent.

Basically you are tring to name an abstract base class here, which has some options:

- [C# Class naming convention: Is it BaseClass or ClassBase or AbstractClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826821/c-sharp-class-naming-convention-is-it-baseclass-or-classbase-or-abstractclass)
- [Naming conventions for abstract classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429470/naming-conventions-for-abstract-classes/429494#429494)
- [I don’t like the “Base” suffix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/12/16/basesuffix.aspx)