# Trying to use File Upload in Listview? Update not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Here is my ListView. I'm using the **OnItemCommand** to reference the code in code-behind. Here I'm trying to **Update** the database with the new **FileUpload** control.

```
 <%--Listview--%>
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="livLocation" class="container"
    DataKeyNames="LocationID"
    DataSourceID="sdsListViewLocation"
    EmptyDataText="No data to display"
    InsertItemPosition="FirstItem"
    OnItemInserted="livLocation_ItemInserted"
    OnItemUpdated="livLocation_ItemUpdated"
    OnItemDeleted="livLocation_ItemDeleted"
    OnItemCanceling="livLocation_ItemCanceling"
    OnItemCommand="livLocation_ItemCommand">
</asp:ListView>
```

The **Insert** works perfectly fine. When an **Update** is executed a Null error is thrown for all **FindControls**. I believe for some reason the **FindControls** are not working for the **Update**. I have tried giving each control their own id's but that still didn't fix the problem. I have been referencing this post but nothing has helped so far: [Upload images with fileupload within a Listview asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191412/upload-images-with-fileupload-within-a-listview-asp-net)

```
 protected void livLocation_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //
        if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
        {
            // Find controls on insert.
            TextBox txtLocation = (TextBox)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("txtLocation");
            TextBox txtImage = (TextBox)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("txtImage");
            FileUpload fuiImage = (FileUpload)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("fuiImage");

            // Get today's date
            String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-h-m-stt");

            // If file is there to upload.
            if (fuiImage.HasFile)
            {
                // Set path.
                String strFileName = txtLocation.Text + "-" + strDate + ".jpg";
                String strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Image\\Location\\" + strFileName;

                // Save file.
                fuiImage.SaveAs(strPath);

                // Fill Image textbox
                txtImage.Text = strFileName;
            }
            else
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            // Find controls on insert.
            TextBox txtLocation = (TextBox)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("txtLocation");
            TextBox txtImage = (TextBox)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("txtImage");
            FileUpload fuiImage = (FileUpload)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("fuiImage");

            // Get today's date
            String strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-h-m-stt");

            // If file is there to upload.
            if (fuiImage.HasFile)
            {
                // Set path.
                String strFileName = txtLocation.Text + "-" + strDate + ".jpg";
                String strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Image\\Location\\" + strFileName;

                // Save file.
                fuiImage.SaveAs(strPath);

                // Fill Image textbox
                txtImage.Text = strFileName;
            }
            else
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            // Delete file.
            FileUpload fuiImage = (FileUpload)livLocation.InsertItem.FindControl("fuiImage");
            String strPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "Image\\Location\\" + fuiImage.FileName;

            System.IO.File.Delete("strPath");

        }
        else
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you include the sytnax for the ListView of the aspx file..

Comment: @HanyHabib Updated.

Comment: first you should use the sender object its easier for maintainability later.. second the edit index and edit item what are their values?

Comment: @Hany Habib OK I will do that. I'm not sure what you mean by those values?

Comment: the value for edittem property : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.edititem?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @HanyHabib I did use or set any values for the EditItem Property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210502/discussion-between-isiah-jones-and-hany-habib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed its always nice to use the sender object for better maintainability later. for your issue kindly visit the following link to get the edited item as your syntax is not correct: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemediting?view=netframework-4.8

it shows more details about item editing and how to fetch the edited item with the new edit index.

the
`(TextBox)livLocation.InsertItem` is incorrect it must be `EditItem` 
so it will be `(FileUpload)(sender as ListView).EditItem.FindControl.....`

Comment: You have to use (FileUpload)livLocation.EditItem.FindControl

Comment: will include it :)

Comment: Any suggestion when using Delete?